# Customize Mailer by inheriting from Devise::Mailer

Tags: devise, mailer

I found this great tutorial on Github about how to create a custom mailer from Devise.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

I implemented the code and the logic makes complete sense to me however when I deploy, I can't get the code to work when I set my config.mailer = 'MyMailer' in initialize/devise.rb. There are no errors in the terminal and it seems that everything got processed just like normal however the email never makes it to the inbox.

If I change config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer', the email gets delivered correctly.  However since MyMailer inherits from Devise::Mailer, shouldn't it work?

Is anyone else having this issue?  Any ideas what I can do to troubleshoot?

Here is my "mailers/my_mailer.rb":

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.   
  # helper :devise # gives access to all helpers defined within `devise_helper`.
  #include Devise::Controllers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  def invoice_payment_failed_email(user, listing)
    @user = user
    @listing = listing
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Payment Failed')
  end
end
```

Here is my "initializers/devise.rb":

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = ENV["DEVISE_SECRET_KEY"]

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = 'MyMailer'
```

Here is my call to the deliver the mail:

```
# email customer
MyMailer.invoice_payment_failed_email(@user, @listing).deliver
```

*Update: 
OMG... after a whole day of racking my brain trying to figure this out, it turns out that the code logic is fine but the problem was that my From: needed to match the Postmark sender accounts.  This is why I wasn't getting any terminal errors.  The deliver request was being sent correctly to Postmark but since my From address wasn't matching, postmark just never delivered the email!

Comment: Maybe if you post a code snippet of what you have done we can have a better idea of where things may be going wrong.

Comment: Good point @embedded_guy Thanks for comment.  First time for me to post a question on Stackoverflow so bear with me.

Comment: OMG... after a whole day of racking my brain trying to figure this out, it turns out that the code logic is fine but the problem was that my From: needed to match the Postmark sender accounts.  This is why I wasn't getting any terminal errors.  The deliver request was being sent correctly to Postmark but since my From address wasn't matching, postmark just never delivered the email!

Comment: Nice! You should put that as an 'answer' to your own question so that it shows up as answered.  Good work working through it.